# How can I create a maven artifact that is compatible with exactly two versions of another artifact?

Tags: maven

I need to create a maven artifact (`org.foo.bar:blarb:1.0.0`) that is dependent on exactly two versions of another artifact (`org.blab.har:har:1.7.0` and `org.blab.har:har:1.8.0`, `1.7.1` and `1.8.1` are not allowed).

Others will be consuming my artifact downstream.  Unless they explicitly specify, I want the default `har` artifact used to be `1.7.0`.  But, there can be something added to the pom to specify `1.8.0`.  (If it is not possible to specify a lower version as the default, I can live with `1.8.0` being the default, but would prefer not to.)

Can you show me a snippet that I would place in the blarb pom so that this can happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is to use [version ranges](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-enforcer-plugin/rules/versionRanges.html).

You could try specifying the following in the dependency for `org.blab.har:har`

```
<version>[1.7.0],[1.8.0]</version>
```

This will indicate to maven to pick either `1.7.0` or `1.8.0`.  I guess the default would `1.8.0` (the higher version)

Comment: Very cool.  I didn't know that maven version ranges were so flexible.  I come from the OSGi world, where this is not possible.  Presumably then, if an artifact wanted to force the 1.7.0 version, it would just explicitly declare a dependency on `org.blab.har:har` and add <version>1.7.0</version> in the dependency declaration?